# Heroku django app crashing (H10) after page acess

Tags: python, django, heroku

well, my app is working fine locally but it's crashing after trying to access on Heroku. I'm using keras (and tensorflow) on it and maybe that's the reason, requirements are ok, and the building show no problems. If it helps, here is my log...

```
020-05-13T22:08:18.257805+00:00 app[web.1]:   np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
2020-05-13T22:08:18.780008+00:00 app[web.1]: System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
2020-05-13T22:08:18.997067+00:00 app[web.1]: May 13, 2020 - 22:08:18
2020-05-13T22:08:18.997196+00:00 app[web.1]: Django version 3.0.6, using settings 'bens.settings'
2020-05-13T22:08:18.997197+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
2020-05-13T22:08:18.997198+00:00 app[web.1]: Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
2020-05-13T22:11:08.154538+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-14T00:10:44.353952+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py` by user
2020-05-14T00:11:11.348754+00:00 heroku[run.7381]: State changed from starting to up
2020-05-14T00:11:11.703430+00:00 heroku[run.7381]: State changed from up to complete
2020-05-14T00:12:23.470671+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=brec.herokuapp.com request_id=43829cd6-5114-4236-9f6f-563be3bdb200 fwd="177.135.10.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2020-05-14T00:12:23.325313+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=brec.herokuapp.com request_id=ea292b42-6010-47bd-b527-6019af8f60d1 fwd="177.135.10.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2020-05-14T00:12:25.948768+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=brec.herokuapp.com request_id=2759d82e-f504-4b57-885d-56e6578c178f fwd="177.135.10.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2020-05-14T00:12:44.661605+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=brec.herokuapp.com request_id=01e5d982-a071-4472-aade-da2c80b3ae0a fwd="177.135.10.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2020-05-14T00:12:45.611089+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=brec.herokuapp.com request_id=ecc948d7-ba13-4192-a0d1-84090028bdb4 fwd="177.135.10.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Main reason for H10 crash is usually because heroku app fails to bind to port to solve this ensure that your port is being set dynamically. something along the lines of :
`process.env.PORT || 3000`
this means that it would run locally on 3000 if you haven't defined any in env but heroku would be able to assign it a dynamic port.

Comment: That worked for h10, but I still have a problem with app boot timeout (h20), do you have any advice like that for this error?

Comment: "heroku ps:restart" seems to fix it sometimes